# Direction of static friction force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, free-body-diagram

A board lies on top of an uniform cylinders which lie on a fixed plane inclined at angle $\theta$. There is friction in all contact surfaces. If there is no slipping between any of the surfaces, is the static friction force between the cylinder and the board in the direction of motion or is it the opposite direction? Why?

Appreciate.

Comment: Is the inclined plane smooth or rough?

Comment: Frictional forces are in such a direction as to prevent relative motion between two bodies (static) or to reduce the relative motion between two bodies (kinetic).

Comment: It will be opposite to direction of motion on the cylinders and due to newtons 3rd law, towards the direction of motion on the board